# While uploading image using react native fetch blob, file gets uploaded but the file size is 0?

Tags: react-native, react-native-fetch-blob

The file is image is uploaded but the file size is 0 and image cannot be viewed. Also, after upload button is pressed the app freezes and gets closed itself. Below is the code that i have written.

```
uploadingPhotos() 
{ 
    RNFetchBlob.fetch('POST','localhost/uploadingImage.php',
        {
            Authorization: "Bearer access-token",
            otherHeader: "foo",
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
        [
            {name: 'image', filename: 'image.png', type: 'image/png', data:RNFetchBlob.wrap(this.state.data)},
        ])
        .then((resp) => {
           // ...
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            // ...
        })
}


uploadingImage.php
<?php

$target_dir="uploads";

$target_dir=$target_dir."/".rand().'_'.time().".jpeg";

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$target_dir)){
  echo json_encode([
    "Message"=>"The file has been uploaded.",
    "Status"=>"OK"
]);

}
else{
echo json_encode([
    "Message"=>"Sorry, there was an error.",
    "Status"=>"Error"
]);
}

?>
```

Comment: You should at least post your code so someone can help you.

Comment: Is there any solution?